# Problema con fechas en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy teniendo un problema que mas que de codigo, es de logica. Estoy sacando las fechas de esta forma

```
   `
const fecha = new Date()
const diaNumero = fecha.getDate()
const diaNombre = fecha.getDay() 
const mes = fecha.getMonth()
const dias = ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado']
const meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 
'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre']
   `
```

Y no hay ningun problema, peeero cuando quiero imprimir el dia y fecha dentro de 5 dias con mi codigo:

`${dias[diaNombre+4]} ${diaNumero+5}/${mes}`

Esto me devuelve un "undefined 32/9" y por supuesto, no hay un dia ni un mes que correspondan con eso. Como podria resolver esto?

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con `cuando quiero imprimir el dia y fecha dentro de 5 dias`. Qué es exactamente lo que quieres imprimir de la fecha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente súmale el número de días en milisegundos. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
let dias = 5;  // Días que deseas sumar a la fecha de hoy
var myDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(dias*24*60*60*1000));

let options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
};

console.log(myDate.toLocaleString('es-MX', options))

// Si quieres dia y mes separados:
let dia = myDate.toLocaleString('es-MX', { weekday: 'long' });
let mes = myDate.toLocaleString('es-MX', { month: 'long' });

console.log(`Día: ${dia}     Mes: ${mes} `)
```